# React Native, Map JSON

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am having trouble figuring out how to map this JSON correctly in React Native. Do I need to rewrite this json?

This is the json

```
"rewards" : {
    "0" : {
      "entries" : 0,
      "image" : "url",
      "name" : "PlayStation 4 Pro 1TB Console",
      "url" : "",
      "price" : 399.99
    },
    "1" : {
      "entries" : 0,
      "image" : "url",
      "name" : "Xbox One S 500GB",
      "url" : "",
      "price" : 249.99
    },
    {...}
```

Here is what I tried for mapping

```
renderItems(){
  const{rewards} = this.props;

  return rewards.map((data, i) => {
    return (<Text> {data[i].name} </Text>)
  })
}
```

Comment: is `rewards` a part of your json or are you trying to name your json `rewards`?

Comment: rewards is the collection name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you’ll need to rewrite the JSON because [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is expecting rewards to be an array of objects. For example:

```
{
  "rewards": [{
    "entries" : 0,
    "image" : "url",
    "name" : "PlayStation 4 Pro 1TB Console",
    "url" : "",
    "price" : 399.99
  },
  {
    "entries" : 0,
    "image" : "url",
    "name" : "Xbox One S 500GB",
    "url" : "",
    "price" : 249.99
  }]
}
```

You’ll also want to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on the rewards prop if you’re not already. Here is an example of how you might use JSON.parse when rendering the component with the rewards prop:

```
render() {
  const rewardsJSON = '{"rewards":[{"entries":0,"image":"url","name":"PlayStation 4 Pro 1TB Console","url":"","price":399.99},{"entries":0,"image":"url","name":"Xbox One S 500GB","url":"","price":249.99}]}';

  return (
    <YOUR_COMPONENT
      rewards=JSON.parse(rewardsJSON).rewards 
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: I am still running into an issue after changing my json. Could you give an example of the JSON.parse(rewards) ?

Comment: Can you describe the issue you’re seeing?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example of how you might use JSON.parse on the rewards JSON.

Comment: Have you had a chance to give this a try?

Answer (score 0):

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) should be called on an array. `rewards` is not an array here, so a solution would be to convert it to an array first.

Suppose your json is this:

```
const myJson = 
{
  "rewards" : {
    "0" : {
      "entries" : 0,
      "image" : "url",
      "name" : "PlayStation 4 Pro 1TB Console",
      "url" : "",
      "price" : 399.99
    },
    "1" : {
      "entries" : 0,
      "image" : "url",
      "name" : "Xbox One S 500GB",
      "url" : "",
      "price" : 249.99
    }
}
```

You can dynamically convert it (with any length) to an array:

```
let index = 0
let dataArr = []
while (myJson.rewards[index]) {
    arr.push(myJson.rewards[index])
    index++
}
```

*hopping the above code is clear enough...*

So now the `dataArr` contains your data like:

```
dataArr = [{
    "entries" : 0,
    "image" : "url",
    "name" : "PlayStation 4 Pro 1TB Console",
    "url" : "",
    "price" : 399.99
  },
  {
    "entries" : 0,
    "image" : "url",
    "name" : "Xbox One S 500GB",
    "url" : "",
    "price" : 249.99
  }]
```

And finally it's the time to map it as you want:

```
return dataArr.map((data, i) => (<Text key={i}> {data.name} </Text>))
```